# Angular2+, check if value with class definition exists in array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Typescript:

```
heroes = [
    new Hero('Windstorm', 1),
    new Hero('Bombasto', 13),
    new Hero('Magneta', 15),
    new Hero('Tornado', 22)
  ];

add(val: string) {
  if (val && !this.heroes.includes(new Hero(val))) {
    alert(this.heroes.includes(new Hero(val)));
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(val));
  }
}

export class Hero {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public id?: number
  ) { }
}
```

Html:

```
<input #box (keyup)="0" (keyup.enter)="onKey(box.value)">
<button (click) = "add(box.value)">Add</button>
```

I want to create a add button that checks whether or not the value exists in my array (name in class `Hero`) and if it does, don't add it.  Only add typed out string if it doesn't already exist in array for key `name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `includes()` like this because it will look for that exact object in the array, which it will never find because you just created it. You need to check by value. One way to do this is to see if [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the heroes have a particular name:

```
add(val: string) {
  // it is not the case that some heroes are named val
  if (val && !this.heroes.some(hero => hero.name === val )) {
    this.heroes.push(new Hero(val));
  }
}
```

This assumes each hero should have a unique name. If you want to allow heroes with duplicate names in the array, you'll need some other property that defines uniqueness like a unique ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can use findIndex() to check if the element exist in the array

```
    add(value:string) {

       if (this.heros.findIndex(x => x.name === value) === -1) {
        this.heroes.push(new Hero(value));
     } 
  }
```